# How to use try catch in lambda expression (JAVA)?

Tags: java, class, lambda, expression, option-type

I have to work with lambda expressions. In this case the try block have create a JSON Object with the input strings. But I must implement that, if the creation doesn't work, it should return an `Optional.Empty()`  instead of `null`.
How can I do that ?
In the current situation, the workflow stops, till the catch happens. So the other strings are ignored.

```
private Optional<JSONObject> testFile (Optional<String>  jsonFileContent)
{
    try
    {
        return jsonFileContent.map(fileContent -> new JSONObject(jsonFileContent)); // this lambda expression needs to be extended
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Never return `null` from a method declared to return an `Optional`, Instead return `Optional.empty()`.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a good way to handle errors, because:

- If something goes wrong, neither you nor anyone who calls your code will have any idea why the operation failed.
- What will you tell end users?  “Something went wrong but we have no idea what, so you can’t do anything about it, and don’t bother trying to tell us either”?

If you aren’t sure of the best way to deal with an exception, don’t catch it at all.  Instead, declare your method to throw it, and let a caller who is prepared to handle it deal with the exception.  For example, a user interface might catch the exception and provide some of its details to the end user.

```
private Optional<JSONObject> testFile(Optional<String> jsonFileContent)
throws JSONException
{
    if (jsonFileContent.isPresent())
    {
        return Optional.of(new JSONObject(jsonFileContent.get()));
    }
    else
    {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

A note about catching exceptions:

Most classes which descend from RuntimeException in Java SE are meant to indicate programmer errors.  Examples would be:

- NullPointerException
- IndexOutOfBoundsException
- IllegalArgumentException

When these occur, they indicate your program logic is broken.  You are not supposed to recover from them; you are supposed to notice them and fix the code responsible.  Catching them and suppressing them will not make your program work.

Such exceptions should never be caught.  This also means you should never write `catch (Exception …)` or `catch (RuntimeException …)`.  If you must write a `catch` block, catch only the exceptions you absolutely need to catch.

But the better option is simply not to catch anything and declare your method with `throws JSONException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a method which would create a 
new JSONObject(jsonFileContent).

And you will wrap the logic in your method in try with catch and will return null  if an exception occurred.

Actually then after you invoked map you can do filter and then findFirst which is null and as findFirst returns Optional it 
will return an empty Optional as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Optional<JSONObject> testFile (Optional<String>  jsonFileContent)
  {
       try{
            return jsonFileContent.map(fileContent -> a(fileContent));
        }
          catch(Exceptione)
{
     return null;
}
Optional a(Optional<String> jsonFileContent) {
    try{
        return new JSONObject(jsonFileContent); // this lambda expression needs to be extended
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```